# Непонятный пример по XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Разбираю пример из книги Core Java, Volume II – Advanced Features by Cay S. Horstmann про Xpath. Вот полный пример:

```java
public class XPathTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {            
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    builder.setEntityResolver(CatalogManager.catalogResolver(
        CatalogFeatures.defaults(), 
        Paths.get("xpath/catalog.xml").toAbsolutePath().toUri()));      

    XPathFactory xpfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath path = xpfactory.newXPath();
    
    try (var in = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        String filename;

        if (args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Input file: ");
            filename = in.nextLine();
        }
        else
            filename = args[0];
    
        Document doc = builder.parse(filename);
        var done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            System.out.print("XPath expression (empty line to exit): " );

            String expression = in.nextLine();

            if (expression.trim().isEmpty())
                done = true;
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    XPathEvaluationResult<?> result = path.evaluateExpression(expression, doc);

                    if (result.type() == XPathEvaluationResult.XPathResultType.NODESET)
                    {
                        for (Node n : (XPathNodes) result.value())
                        System.out.println(description(n));
                    }
                    else if (result.type() == XPathEvaluationResult.XPathResultType.NODESET)
                        System.out.println((Node) result.value());
                    else
                        System.out.println(result.value());
                } 
                catch (XPathExpressionException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }          
        }   
    }
}
```

Непонятна следующая часть кода:

```java
if (result.type() == XPathEvaluationResult.XPathResultType.NODESET)
{
    for (Node n : (XPathNodes) result.value())
    System.out.println(description(n));
}
else if (result.type() == XPathEvaluationResult.XPathResultType.NODESET)
    System.out.println((Node) result.value());
else
    System.out.println(result.value());
```

Почему здесь проверяется одно и то же условие дважды? Я предполагал, что метод `type()` как-то изменяет переменную `result` во время выполнения, но нет – он просто возвращает текущий тип элемента XML. Может, во втором `if` имелась в виду проверка на `NODE`, а не `NODESET`?

Comment: ну скорее всего тут банальная опечатка и во втором случае должно проверяться с `XPathEvaluationResult.XPathResultType.NODE`

Comment: Спасибо, я так и думал.

Comment: предлагаю закрыть вопрос, т.к. он не очень полезен сообществу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут опечатка в книге, второе условие никогда не сработает. Замените на:

```
...
else if (result.type() == XPathEvaluationResult.XPathResultType.NODE)
...
```

В таких случаях, уточняйте в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/XPathEvaluationResult.XPathResultType.html).